# Designing loosely coupled components in .NET - Provider Pattern

Tags: .net, design-patterns

I have been told that the [Provider pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Provider_model) is a way to design loosely coupled components. I am working on designing an API. Could you please point to links where Provider pattern is explained. I found one [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/adilakhter/archive/2008/11/02/ProviderDesignPattern.aspx), are there any more that describe provider pattern using .net as the framework

Comment: Have you considered using the strategy pattern or the orchestrator pattern?  Both sound like they might be a good fit for problem (loosely coupled components).

Comment: Almost all design patterns are by definition intended to help with decoupling your components.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In Juval Lowy's WCF book he calls the pattern the [Bridge pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bridge_pattern). [dofactory](http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/PatternBridge.aspx) has some good stuff on it too.

I've recently been collecting some links on the provider pattern for an MS exam I was studying for (70-568). Here's the list- more than you'll ever need to know about the Provider Model:

- [Provider Model Design Pattern and Specification, Part 1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972319.aspx) (old but detailed).
- [The ASP.NET 2.0 Provider Model](http://download.microsoft.com/download/2/a/e/2aeabd28-3171-4b95-9363-22150625a6a5/ASP.NET%20Provider%20Model.pdf). 136 pages- a tomb of Provider Model information.
- [ProviderBase](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.provider.providerbase.aspx)- the base class for all provider implementations.
- [Don’t forget to add `<clear/>` when adding providers.](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/11/20/common-gotcha-don-t-forget-to-clear-when-adding-providers.aspx)
- [Configuring Providers](http://www.developer.com/net/asp/article.php/3569166).
- [Using the ASP.NET provider functionality in Windows based apps](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384297.aspx).
- [Implementing a Membership Provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f1kyba5e.aspx).
- [Implementing a Role Provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8fw7xh74.aspx).
- [Creating a custom site map provider](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020133925/https://aspnet.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/020106-1.aspx).
- [Implementing a Profile Provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0580x1f5.aspx).
- [Creating a custom DB profile provider](http://www.theserverside.net/tt/articles/content/CreatingProfileProvider/CreatingProfileProvider.html).
- [Session State Providers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa478952.aspx).
- [Implementing a Session-State Store Provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178587.aspx).

Comment: Thank you for the links Richard!!! Each demonstrates a way to implement Provider Pattern

Comment: Glad it helped. It is a great pattern.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a white paper from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972319.aspx) (linking to part 1)

Here is another source for [Provider Design Patterns in ASP.NET 2.0](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/webmaster3/ProviderPattern12242007184126PM/ProviderPattern.aspx) from C-Sharp Corner

Answer (score 2):

the most elegant solution for achieving loose coupling is DI and IoC.

Have a look here:

- [Design Pattern IoC and DI](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/IOCandDI.aspx)
- [Inversion of Control and Dependency
  Injection: Working with Windsor
  Container](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa973811.aspx)

Have fun :)

Answer (score 0):

MSDN offers a walk-through for the [ASP.NET Provider Pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972319.aspx)