# What is an ASP.NET Provider?

Tags: c#, asp.net, provider

What is the meaning of "Provider" in ASP.NET Provider? For example when we are speaking about `AuthorizationRuleProvider`, `connectionStrings.providerName`, ...?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's a design pattern: The [Provider model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Provider_model). There is some good information in this SO Q&A as well: [Designing loosely coupled components in .NET - Provider Pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/859523/designing-loosely-coupled-components-in-net-provider-pattern)

Answer (score 3):

It's just a concrete implementation of an abstract interface. You can select an appropriate provider to fulfill the requirements of the interface at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

And if you want to implement the Provider pattern in your application, take a look at this [.NET Provider Model Template for Visual Studio](https://cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=26) (shameless plug).

Answer (score 0):

As other answered above, it is the provider pattern. I would like to add that the ***Provider patter***n is an alias for the ***Strategy pattern***.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Provider_model