# Provider pattern in C#

Tags: c#, design-patterns, provider

Am trying to understand provider pattern in detail , When I use a Abstract class and inherit a providerbase with abstract method then create two class when implements the abstract class  and abstract method,
The Query here is I am not clear with this understanding  as this can be achieved with a simple abstract class and implementing a class , So why are we really inheriting a ProviderBase ? I tried a sample design below , can someone help me in the provider Base class usage in Microsoft please . Thanks

```
using System.Configuration.Provider;

namespace POC_Driver
{
  public abstract class DealNotesProvideBase : ProviderBase
  {
    public abstract void saveData();
  }
}

public class DealNotesAsDatapathProvider : DealNotesProvideBase
{
  public DealNotesAsDatapathProvider()
  {
  }

  public override void saveData()
  {
     // do something 
  }
}

public class AnotherClassProvider : DealNotesProvideBase
{
  public override void saveData()
  {
     // do something 
  }
}

Main()
{
  DealNotesAsDatapathProvider provider = new DealNotesAsDatapathProvider ();
  AnotherClassProvider  anotherclassprovider = new AnotherClassProvider ();
  provider.saveData();
  anotherclassprovider.saveData();
}
```

Comment: What is the actual problem you are trying to solve? Patterns can be useful, but you need to know when and why to use them. I can't say I have ever used the pattern, but I would suggest looking up "dependency injection" for a somewhat related pattern that is quite common.

Comment: As mentioned in the question am trying to understand this pattern and why Microsoft has given a separate ProviderBase class which is under namespace : "System.Configuration.Provider" and what it actually does when it can be achieved from  abstract class .

Comment: Try check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/859523/designing-loosely-coupled-components-in-net-provider-pattern). I agree with @JonasH, that its usage depends of what you've need (except plain curiosity), but you don't tell us your desired purpose. Also it looks a bit obsolete or _veeery_ specific-case usable comparing to much common Factory or Strategy patterns.